# What does it mean by "labor taxes cut is self-financed"?

Tags: economics

I'm reading "Principle of Economics" by Mankiw. In Part III Market and Welfare, Ch 8 "Application: the costs of taxation", it says:

Only 32% of a cut in U.S. labor taxes would be self-financed, the economists note, versus 54% self-financing in Europe. Just over 50% of a cut in U.S. capital taxes would pay for itself, the authors estimate, versus 79% in Europe.

But what does it mean by a tax cut be "self-financing"?

self-financing
adj
(of a student, business, etc.) financing oneself or itself without external grants or aid

So "self-financing" means someone can sustain without external aid. I just could not get it what a tax needs to be "self-financing"

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about introductory economics, not quantitative finance.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich but there's no "introductory economics" forum  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is meant is the so called [Laffer effect or Laffer curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laffer_curve).

The rationale is that when you cut taxes that this will stimulate business and thereby over-compensate the loss in taxes the government originally had.

Comment: i think not. the article is saying US is actually on the *left* side of the Laffer curve. so US need not cut tax to stimulate business.

Comment: @athos: You asked what it means when a tax cut is said to be self-financed and this is the answer. Trust me, I have a PhD in economics and I am a professor and teach this stuff ;-)

Comment: of course you have a better judgement on it. allow me rephrase my question, "Only 32% of a cut in U.S. labor taxes would be self-financed," does this mean that in U.S. if the labor tax rate is 32%, it will collect the most tax?

Comment: If I understand the article correctly it means that the government can cut labour taxes by 32% and still rake in the same amount of taxes (due to accelerating business). Beyond this point, i.e. cutting more than 32%, the government will collect less taxes. (But the article is not very well phrased, in my humble opinion).

Comment: i see. so there are 2 things, first, US is on left side of Laffer curve so a higher rate of tax in that year would raise more taxes; second, after considering business growth, a 32% cut in current tax rate would encourage economy and even harvest more taxes. thanks!